# Can doing the same kind of exercise workout daily provide any good improvements?

Tags: workout-routines, workout, routine, boxing

I've been learning kickboxing from a local trainer in my city for the last 2 months. I've noticed that in one hour of workout he made us to do the same workout exercises with some minor changes. I've read some articles that say if we do the same sets of exercises daily, then our body will adapt to it and won't get expected results. That's why I think the gym guys do different kinds of workouts daily to have some variations.

So does this really matter and is it true?

Answer (score 6):

What you’re describing is [Exercise Adaptation](http://www.sportsci.org/encyc/adaptex/adaptex.html), or, “training plateau”.  It’s a common response to exercise stress.  From the National Academy of Sports…

> The principle of adaptation refers to the process of the body getting
>   accustomed to a particular exercise or training program through
>   repeated exposure. As the body adapts to the stress of the new
>   exercise or training program, the program becomes easier to perform
>   and explains why beginning exercisers are often sore after starting a
>   new routine, but, after doing the same exercise for weeks and months
>   at the same intensity, the exerciser experiences little, if any,
>   muscle soreness. This reinforces the need to constantly vary the
>   exercise and training routine if you want to maximize your results.

However, each of us react differently to the stress.  Some may reach a training plateau where gains are few or non-existent.  While others, with the same stress, can continue to make improvements.  That’s why it’s important to recognize a plateau and make the necessary changes to continue improving.  The key is to always challenge your body.  That may take the form of increasing the intensity, or, changing the order of exercises, sets, and reps.  In my experiences, once a plateau has been reached, I try to take a week off to recharge and refocus my efforts.  My goal is to come back with a fresh approach to my training.

So, to answer your question, adaptation is real and should not derail your training progress if you recognize it and make the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 6):

Most "guys in the gym" have absolutely no idea what they are doing.

There are certain exercises that you can really do pretty much every day for the rest of your life with good results. If you were using a lot of weight, you might want to do them every other day. That's the premise behind most strength training plans: they pick the most valuable barbell lifts and then progressively increase the load.

Outside of scientific-strength-training land, it's pretty normal in the military or martial arts to have calistentics and conditioning. You'll find burpees, pullups, pushups, flutter kicks, bicycle crunches, etc. These aren't the "best" things for you to do, but spending thirty minutes a day doing calistenics is light years better than nothing. A workout like that serves several purposes:

- It's a good warmup for other activities (in your case, kickboxing).
- There's no advanced training. You can easily tell a room of people to start doing jumping jacks and not have to worry about someone throwing a disc.
- It's relatively simple to put a workout together that makes use of whatever you have around.

There's no reason to change exercises for the sake of changing them. Reasons to change generally revolve around picking better exercises and dumping others, in an effort to have a more balanced work effort (ie: pullups *and* pushups rather than two different styles of pushups).